# Directed hyper-edges in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Arc between arrows in TikZ (automata library)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25401/arc-between-arrows-in-tikz-automata-library)

Can anyone tell me if and how I can draw directed hyper-edges in tikz?
Specifically, I'm trying to get an edge starting at one node and ending in two that is connected by some arc to show that this is one hyper-edge instead of two normal edges.

[image: The kind of hyper-edge I want to draw]

I got the screenshot by manually drawing an arc in between to edges in open office and I hope there is a better way to do this in tikz.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25401/)  related or the connections really should look like a sigmoid?

Comment: The edges can be drawn either as two separate edges or as a single path, either is easy to specify using standard TikZ drawing commands.  The main issue is getting that arc, and that's covered by the question that percusse links to.  If you find that that *doesn't* work for you, then please edit your post to explain what difficulties you're having, or why it isn't helpful to you.

Comment: Yes, thanks percusse, that is what I meant. I was searching for the wrong keywords. Not as easy as I hoped, but at least there is a way to do it. The edges in the picture only were sigmoid because I couldn't get open office to do the kind of edge I wanted: both edges would stay on the same path for some time and then bend apart. I managed something close enough with an additional invisible node.

Do you want to add your comment as an answer so I can accept it or what is the stackexchange way of dealing with duplicates?

Comment: Glad that you found what you wanted. I also don't know what to do maybe we should flag the moderator for duplicate. But I wonder if it would count as an unanswered question? Let me try. They will know what to do.

Comment: @percusse Thanks for flagging, the question has already been closed by voting of fellow users.