# Drawing directed hyperedges with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I'm currently working with modelchecking of symbolic dependecy graphs for my semester project in Computer Science, and am dire need of an easy way to draw dependency graphs preferably using TikZ.

My problem is somewhat related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136773/simple-directed-hypergraphs-in-tikz), but i need the arcs to be directed.

A hyperedge `e` is a tuple `e = (v, T)` where `v` is a source node and `T` is the target set. Each element in `T` is a tuple `t = (w, t)` where `w` is either a non-negative integer or a parameter and `t` is a target node.

The follwing example (found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136773/simple-directed-hypergraphs-in-tikz)) does exactly what i need, except i need the arcs to be directed.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\hyperedge}[4][180]{
     \draw (#2.#1) ++(#1:.5)  edge (#2) edge (#3) edge (#4);    
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    y=.7cm, x=1cm,
    every edge/.append style={thick}
]

\node (c) at (0,0) {c};
\node (a) at (1,1) {d};
\node (b) at (1,-1) {e};


\hyperedge[0]{c}{b}{a}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried adding `->` as an option to the *tikzpicture*, but this resulted in arrows not just to the target set but also to the source node.

Comment: `every edge/.append style={thick,->}`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Same result as adding `->` as an option to *tikzpicture*. It produces arrows pointing towards either ends of the hyperedge, i.e. also procuces an arrow pointing towards the source node.

Comment: I see, sorry. Do you need to do anything more complex, or is the defined `\hypergraph` command sufficient? Graph drawing isn't my forte, but for this specific case you could modify the `\draw` command in the definition of `\hypergraph` to `\draw (#2.#1) ++(#1:.5)  edge (#2) edge[->] (#3) edge[->] (#4);`.  I can add an answer if that is good enough.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. THANK YOU! That was exactly what i needed :) PLease add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this specific case you can modify the `\hypergraph` command to read

```
\newcommand{\hyperedge}[4][180]{
     \draw (#2.#1) ++(#1:.5)  edge (#2) edge[->] (#3) edge[->] (#4);    
}
```

which will add arrows to two of the `edge`s, those leading to the target nodes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\hyperedge}[4][180]{
     \draw (#2.#1) ++(#1:.5)  edge (#2) edge[->] (#3) edge[->] (#4);    
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    y=.7cm, x=1cm,
    every edge/.append style={thick}
]

\node (c) at (0,0) {c};
\node (a) at (1,1) {d};
\node (b) at (1,-1) {e};


\hyperedge[0]{c}{b}{a}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```